# Using SED or AWK to remove all quotes in a specific CSV column

Tags: regex, awk, sed, replace, quotes

I have a file with a bunch of CSV lines with values with and without quotes like so :

```
"123","456",,17,"hello," how are you this, fine, highly caffienated morning,","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","XYZ", 
"345","737",,16,"Heading to a "meeting", unprepared while trying to be "awake","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","ACD",
```

The **fifth** column is a text column which has escaped or unescaped double quotes. I am trying to get rid of all the quotes in this column so it looks like this

```
"123","456",,17,"hello, how are you this, fine, highly caffeinated morning,","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","XYZ", 
"345","737",,16,"Heading to a meeting, unprepared while trying to be awake","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","ACD",
```

Any ideas how to achieve this using SED or AWK, or any other unix tools? Much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please do let us know if this is a proper csv file? Looks like `,,16`from line is NOT having `""` around values?

Comment: The first four are ok, you don't know where the fifth ends in you can't use comma or quote to delimit it but the sixth contains a date.  Assuming there is no ISO formatted date in the fifth column you can use that to know where the fifth column ends.

Comment: Judging by the spelling of "caffeinated", you did *not* copy-and-paste this example.

Comment: There's generally no robust way to do things like this. How is it supposed to know which are the proper quotes and which are the ones that need to be removed?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I think this is exactly the point of the entire question. We have a CSV file which is invalid, how can we make it into a valid one.

Comment: @kvantour, yeah you are right. But then may be we can look for Tools which are good in csv file fixing, rather than re-inventing the wheel  :) This is just a thought though(personally I have not worked on this kind of issue till now).

Answer (score 2):

With awk, you can do something like this that avoid [very complex regex](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). The fact that only the fifth column is broken, that the previous columns do not contain commas, and that we know there are a fixed number of columns make it easy to repair :

*Edited using `gsub` for portability as suggested by Ed Morton*

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    {
        for(i=6; i<=NF-3;i++){
            $5 = $5 FS $i
        }
    }
    {
         gsub(/"/, "", "g", $5)
    }
    {print $1,$2,$3,$4,"\""$5"\"",$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}
    ' <file>
```

Output :

```
"123","456",,17,"hello, how are you this, fine, highly caffienated morning,","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","XYZ", 
"345","737",,16,"Heading to a meeting, unprepared while trying to be awake","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","ACD",
```

If you want to escape quotes, you can use this :

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    {
        for(i=6; i<=NF-3;i++){
            $5 = $5 FS $i
        }
    }
    {
         gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$5);
         gsub(/"/,"\\\"",$5);
         $5="\""$5"\"";
    }
    {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}
    ' <file>
```

Output :

```
"123","456",,17,"hello,\" how are you this, fine, highly caffienated morning,","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","XYZ", 
"345","737",,16,"Heading to a \"meeting\", unprepared while trying to be \"awake","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","ACD",
```

Comment: What if in the 5th there is a date like "2018-05-29" ? The regex complexity is just defined by trying to match most possible cases. It's high likely that a date can be in the 5th column. It's less likely that a date ISO formatted can be found in the 5th.

Comment: Your output add \" at the begin and end of the 5th.

Comment: @naurel good point, I've changed the script to avoid using date formats. My remark about avoiding complex regex is not a criticism of your solution, I mentioned that because OP chose the `regex` tag for his question. Thank you for helping improving my solution !

Comment: Your method is excellent but there is an extra assumption needed: any column before `$5` cannot have a comma. If `$1` has a comma, this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
,\d{2}\,(.*),\"\S{25}\",\"\w{3}"
```

It was made based on your examples. The goal is just to capture de fifth column. Like @Jerry Jeremiah suggested the point was to use the date wich will always be 25 char long. To prevent some missmatch I've also taken in account the 2 digits presents before the fifth and the 3 letters/digit after the date.
[Regex101v1](https://regex101.com/r/CDysrE/1)

We can also use a "stronger" regex by looking for the exact date match

```
,\d{2}\,(.*),\"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\w\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}\",\"\w{3}"
```

[Regex101v2](https://regex101.com/r/CDysrE/2)

With theses regex you'll be able to extract the fifth column using group. To go deeper in your question you can do this in bash :

```
regex='^(.*,[0-9]{2}\,")(.*)(",\"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\",\"[a-zA-Z]{3}".*$)'
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
    then
        before=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fifth=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        after=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        reworked_fifth="${fifth//\"}"
        echo ${before}${reworked_fifth}${after}
    else
        echo "Line didnt match the regex"
  fi
done < /my/file/path
```

I had to change the regex since my bash didn't take `\d` and `\w`. No need to sed or awk anything with this. Bash can handle it alone.

Comment: Your thinking on `No need to sed or awk anything with this. Bash can handle it alone.` is backwards. This is the type of job that awk was created to do and is not a job that a shell is well suited for even if you can make it work, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). You shouldn't be trying to avoid standard UNIX tools. You have at least one bug in your shell script btw - unquoted variables in the `echo`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: You've got me wrong, sorry english is not my primary language. I just wanted to say that you can achieve this without awk or sed. But I do think that Corentin solution was better than mine. He had my upvote for it.

Comment: @naurel this worked really well, thanks! Besides replacing the quotes, how can i also include a comma as well in ${fifth//\"}" ? thanks so much

Comment: As far as I know you'll need to do it in 2 times. One time for the comma and one time for the quote. Whatever the order.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to answer in a generic way. To give an example:

```
 "a","b","c","d"
```

How is this interpreted (if we remove the quotes from the fields of interest):

```
"a","b","c","d"  (4 fields)
"a,b","c","d"    (3 fields, $1 messed up)
"a","b,c","d"    (3 fields, $2 messed up)
"a","b","c,d"    (3 fields, $3 messed up)
"a,b,c","d"      (2 fields, $1 messed up)
"a,b","c,d"      (2 fields, $1 and $2 messed up)
"a","b,c,d"      (2 fields, $2 messed up)
"a,b,c,d"        (1 field , $1 messed up)
```

The only way this can be solved is by having the following knowledge:

- How many fields does my CSV have
- There is maximum one fields messed up
- We know which field is messed up

The following awk program will help you fix it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ere="[^,]*|\042[^\042]"}
       { head=tail=""; mid=$0 }
       # extract the head which is correct
       (n>1) {
          ere_h="^"
          for(i=1;i<n;++i) ere_h = ere_h (ere_h=="^" ? "",",") "(" ere ")"
          match(mid,ere_h); head=substr(mid,RSTART,RLENGTH)
          mid = substr(mid,RLENGTH+1)
       }
       # extract the tail which is correct
       (nf>n) {
          ere_t="$"
          for(i=n+1;i<=nf;++i) ere_t = "(" ere ")" (ere_h=="$" ? "",",") ere_t
          match(mid,ere_t); tail=substr(mid,RSTART,RLENGTH)
          mid = substr(mid,1,RSTART-1)
       }
       # correct the mid part
       { gsub(/\042/,"",mid)
         mid = (mid ~ /^,/) ? ( ",\042" substr(mid,2) ) : ( "\042" mid )
         mid = (mid ~ /,$/) ? ( substr(mid,1,length(mid)-1) "\042," ) : (mid "\042" )
       }
       # print the stuff
       { print head mid tail }' n=5 nf=7 file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and assuming you know how many fields there should be in each line:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numFlds  = 8
    badFldNr = 5
}
match($0,"^(([^,]*,){"badFldNr-1"})(.*)((,[^,]*){"numFlds-badFldNr"})",a) {
    gsub(/"/,"",a[3])
    print a[1] "\"" a[3] "\"" a[4]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"123","456",,17,"hello, how are you this, fine, highly caffienated morning,","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","XYZ",
"345","737",,16,"Heading to a meeting, unprepared while trying to be awake","2018-05-29T18:58:10-05:00","ACD",
```

With other awks you can do the same with a couple of calls to match() and variables instead of the array.

Comment: This might fail if there are commas in the first fields.

Comment: Right, or in the last fields. It'll only work if all lines of the CSV look like the sample in the question in that there will be no commas within any field other than the 5th.